# Dojo: There are something about 'class extend'?

Tags: javascript, dojo, extend

I want to make a new widget javascript class [Label] it look like dijit.button.
So I look at the source code of dijit Button and try to copycat it.

It start with declare and I use dijit.form._FormWidget as a superclass.

But when I run it on the web page it doesn't work, I debug with Firebug in Firefox and it return "this.containerNode is null"

I can't figure how to set containerNode parameter.

Can anyone answer me, what the problem does it cause it to happen?

P.S. I'm a bit new to javascript.

Comment: Hmm, can you show some code? dijit.form.Button sets containerNode in its template file (templates/Button.html). Are you using a template file for your widget? If you don't you have to build your HTML (including setting the containerNode) in your widget's `buildRendering` method.

Comment: Are you an experienced Dojo developer?  What you're attempting is not trivial and you'll need to understand quite a bit of how Dojo works before you can should do it.  Otherwise, it is very easy to introduce subtle bugs and errors that you'll never be able to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple dijit for your reference. The JavaScript:

```
dojo.declare("com.example.Label", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    templateString: dojo.cache("com.example", "templates/Label.html"),
    value : ""
});
```

The HTML template:

```
<div><span>${value}</span></div>
```

Usage:

```
var label = new com.example.Label({value : "Hello"});
```